# .BAT - Launch a .exe with arguments where the .exe location and arguments are strings

Tags: string, batch-file, location

Trying to use the code below to run the following command in a .bat file

```
c:\program files (x86)\Team Mediaportal\Mediaportal\TV Thumbnailer\ffmpeg.exe -ss 720 -itsoffset -5 -i "c:\tv recordings\sample recording.mpg" -vframes 1 -y "C:\tv recordings\sample recording.jpg"
```

---

```
Set "FFMpeg_Location=c:\Program Files (x86)\Team Mediaportal\Mediaportal\TV Thumbnailer"

rem or Set "FFMpeg_Location=c:\Program Files (x86)\Team Mediaportal\Mediaportal\TV Thumbnailer\ffmpeg.exe" , whichever is easier :D

Set "Video_Path=c:\tv recordings\"

Set "Video_File=sample recording"

%FFMpeg_Location%\FFMpeg.exe -ss 720 -itsoffset -5 -i "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.mpg" -vframes 1 -y "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.jpg"
```

---

PS. I'd like the .bat to continue after ffmpeg has finished running, as I am using ffmpeg to process a lot of files inside a for loop.  Also I'd prefer not to change the working directory of the .bat file by doing cd c:\pro...\tv thumbnailer\ as that would break my script.

---

**EDIT: I solved my problem by using the call statement :D**

```
call "%FFMpeg_Location%\FFMpeg.exe" -ss 720 -itsoffset -5 -i "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.mpg -vframes 1 -y "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.jpg"
```

Comment: So what is not working? I don't see a question.

Comment: I figured it out I have to use

Comment: The last line was giving an error

'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Correct syntax is

call "%FFMpeg_Location%\FFMpeg.exe" -ss 720 -itsoffset -5 -i "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.mpg" -vframes 1 -y "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call "%FFMpeg_Location%\FFMpeg.exe" -ss 720 -itsoffset -5 -i "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.mpg -vframes 1 -y "%Video_Path%%Video_File%.jpg"